# How can i get unique user from order on particular day

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I want chart for number of user purchase from my site. How can i achieve this?

```
$ordersArr = Order::where('vendor_id',$id)
        ->whereBetween('created_at',[$carbonStart,$carbonEnd])
        ->get();
```

My table are as follow 
order

```
id user_id venodr_id  created_at
==================================
 1     1           1      2019-03-30 07:15:03
 2     1           2      2019-03-30 07:20:03
 3     1           1      2019-03-29 07:20:03
 4     1           2      2019-03-29 07:20:03
 5     2           1      2019-03-30 07:15:03
 6     2           2      2019-03-30 07:20:03
 7     2           1      2019-03-29 07:20:03
 8     2           2      2019-03-29 07:20:03
 9     2           2      2019-03-29 07:20:03
```

The result i want is

```
user_id  count  date
  1        2    2019-03-30
  1        2    2019-03-29 
  2        2    2019-03-30
  2        3    2019-03-29
```

Comment: You need to group by `date` and `user_id` and do a `COUNT()` for the extra column.

Comment: Can you explain how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = DB::table('order')
        ->select(DB::raw('user_id,count(*) as vendor_id,created_at as date'))
        ->whereBetween('created_at',[$carbonStart,$carbonEnd])
        ->groupBy('user_id')->get();
```

Comment: Can i get it by eloquent model query??

Comment: Replace DB::table('order') to Order::select ?

Comment: Normally i use eloquent in Model and DB query in controller. Looks easier for me that way.